# I need to set videos dynamically as my sites home page background?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, video

I am trying to make the background of my sites home page be a video that is, through various means, set by the users of the site. Every user will only see one video as the background at any given time. But my problem is that I am looking for some javascript that can accomplish doing this with videos form any site (or a large number of video sites), compatible with as many browsers as possible, as well as being able to take the video and mute or unmute it with a button we have incorporated.

Currently I have found things like tubular.js 
[ http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/ ]
The problem is that only supports youtube.

Also was looking into bigvideo.js and was wondering if this could do what I was looking for in Rails?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML `video` tag. It's supported by all the browsers (including mobile), but the only problem - you have to store videos on your own server/hosting or cdn to have a direct link to the file.

Comment: we dont have any videos stored on our server. We are just using embed.ly to parse the links and then embedding videos on the site.